# Creating an OwinContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the new templates, the owin contexts are created like this:

```
public void ConfigAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
}
```

But it seems like it would be easier to do this:

```
public void ConfigAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
}
```

Is there any reason to do the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature expected of the `CreatePerOwinContext` extension method is `Func<T>`.

`() => new ApplicationDbContext()` has a signature of `Func<T>` and can satisfy the signature.

`ApplicationDbContext.Create` also has a signature of `Func<T>` and can also be used.

The difference is that in the first example, you're creating an anonymous method to return the signature. In the second case, the method signature has already been supplied for you. They are pretty much functionally equivalent, much like how you can hook a lambda expression-created anonymous method up to an `event` in C# or use a method that satisfies the signature.

As for the reasoning, **OWIN** is agnostic to any particular tech and is designed to allow development of applications with a loose coupling between app and hosting of the app (IIS vs Katana vs ???). As a result, OWIN does not know about (or care about) Entity Framework, and so Entity Framework has created a method with a signature to plug into OWIN. This is called interface segregation or loose coupling.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I'm glad that I was not missing anything!  I love anonymous methods - it let's me write less lines of code!